# Codeigniter - AJAX pass array to Model with return

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to send an array to a controller, pass it on to the model and get a return (making sure the entry as successfully entered in the DB).  I can get it to add correctly in the DBase, but I get a return error and can't figure out why.  This code works, but if I move the json_encode line down beneath the outpuString, I get an error (but still adds to the dbase). How do I verify that the record gets entered?

view's JQuery code:

```
function addSongToOndeck(songID, userID) {
            var controllerURL = "<? echo site_url("/getcomps/entercompprocessor/") ?>/";
            $.ajax({
                url: controllerURL,
                type:'POST',
                data: {
                    songID: songID,
                    userID: userID
                 },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(outputString){
                     $('#returnMessage').append(outputString);
                },
                 error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
                    console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                    console.log( "Status: " + status );
                    console.dir( xhr );
                },// End of success function of ajax form
            }); // End of ajax call 
        }
```

My Controller:

```
function entercompprocessor()
{   
        echo json_encode("Successfully added to competition");

        $data = array(
            'song_id' => $this->input->post('songID'),
            'user_id' => $this->input->post('userID')
        );

        $returned['result']= $this->competitions_model->putOnDeck($data);

}
```

my Model:

```
function putOnDeck($dataArr)
{
    $query = $this->db->insert('on_deck', $dataArr);    
    if($query->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        return "added!";
    }
    else
    { 
        return "failed!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your model code to the following:

```
function putOnDeck($dataArr)
{
    if($this->db->insert('on_deck', $dataArr))
    {
        return "added!";
    }
    else
    { 
        return "failed!";
    }
}
```

And then move your json_encode after your $outputstring declaration. The affected_rows() function in codeigniter is looking at existing rows that were affected by the previously executed query. Since you are inserting a new row the value returned will never be > 0.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: But consider to change controller method code because now you are sending success message to view wether insert was successfull or failed. Something like: `if ($returned['result']) { echo json_encode("Successfully added to competition"); } else { echo 'Not successfully added to competition'; }`